# Writting in text file error, QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have this code in QT c++

```
void writeInFile()
{
    QFile file(":/texts/test.txt");
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        in<<"test";
    }
    file.close();
}
```

I want to add "test" to my text file which is in resources with prefix "texts", but this function does nothing, I can't write or read from file when I am oppening it with "QIODevice::ReadWrite" or "QFile::ReadWrite", I can only read from it on readonly mode. Any help or advice welcome.

Comment: why don't you use ./texts/test.txt instead of :/texts/test.txt?

Comment: Is there any difference?

Comment: I honestly don't know

Comment: @SpikeBughdaryan, can you add these line? Make an else block just beneath the if cnodition qDebug() << "error code: " + QString::number(file.error());  I want to see the error code.

Comment: It actually goes into if block, its just doesn't change anything

Comment: @SpikeBughdaryan, actually, you'll have to remove the initial ":" in the beginning of file name. ":" is for resources that are readonly.

Comment: after removing , the error is 

err 5: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Ok, making progress. Give a full path. Like "C:\temp\test.txt"

Comment: Resource files are read only, they are bundled within your binary application file so you cannot write to it. If you have to you can copy the resource file to a local path and the modify the copy, if that is what you want?

Comment: but then i have to override it, how can i swap the original one with its copy?

Comment: @SpikeBughdaryan What do you mean? You cannot change any Qt resource files from your C++ code, only by recompiling your binary file containing the resources!?

Comment: I am creating a game, and im at point where player hits high score, and the text file with high score needs to be override, I dont want to use sql or any other databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt resource files are read-only, as they are put into the binary as "code" - and the application cannot modify itself.

Since editing resources is simply impossible, you should follow the standard approach of caching those files. This means you copy the resource to the local computer and edit that one.

Here is a basic function that does exactly that:

```
QString cachedResource(const QString &resPath) {
    // not a ressource -> done
    if(!resPath.startsWith(":"))
        return resPath;
    // the cache directory of your app
    auto resDir = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::CacheLocation);
    auto subPath = resDir + "/resources" + resPath.mid(1); // cache folder plus resource without the leading :
    if(QFile::exists(subPath)) // file exists -> done
        return subPath;
    if(!QFileInfo(subPath).dir().mkpath("."))
        return {}; //failed to create dir
    if(!QFile::copy(resPath, subPath))
        return {}; //failed to copy file
    // make the copied file writable
    QFile::setPermissions(subPath, QFileDevice::ReadUser | QFileDevice::WriteUser);
    return subPath;
}
```

In short, it copies the resource to a cache location if it does not already exist there and returns the path to that cached resource. One thing to be aware of is that the copy operation presevers the "read-only" permission, which means we have to set permissions manually. If you need different permissions (i.e. execute, or access for the group/all) you can adjust that line.

In your code, you would change the line:

```
QFile file(cachedResource(":/texts/test.txt"));
```

Comment: Thank you I was thinking about that, but after modifying can I replace the copied one with original?

Comment: As stated before - no. It is impossible to replace the original one in the executable (from a technical point) - that would be like changing a tire while your driving your car... But this solution serves the same purpose - except if you want a portable app. (In that case cache the files to the same folder the binary lives in)